# rxImport fails on large dataset

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I've been trying unsuccessfully the past two days to convert a large CSV (9 gigs) into XDF format using the RxImport function.

The process seems to start off well with R server reading in the data chunk by chunk but after a few minutes it slows to a crawl and then fails completely after around 6 hours with Windows stopping the server saying its run out of RAM.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
pd_in_file <- RxTextData("cca_pd_entity.csv", delimiter = ",") #file to import
pd_out_file <- file.path("cca_pd_entity.xdf") #desired output file
pd_data <- rxImport(inData = pd_in_file, outFile = pd_out_file, 
stringsAsFactors = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I'm running Microsoft R Server, version 9.0.1. on a Windows 7 machine with 16gig of RAM.

Thanks

Comment: See if setting the `colInfo` argument helps

Comment: Thank you for suggestion I'll give that a try. I have nearly 300 columns of data, so is it correct to assume I can import a subset of the data and use the rxGetVarInfo command to extract the column information and pass that to the rxImport command instead of having to manually specify each column separately?

Comment: It worked!!! Arg this is so awesome :D Thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 2):

Its been solved using Hong Ooi's recommendation to set the colInfo in the rxTextData. I'm not sure why it made such a big difference but it converted the entire 9gig dataset in less than 2 minutes when it completely failed to import after several hours before.

Comment: what did you set the colInfo argument to?

Comment: @gibbz00 - I imported a sample of data from the CSV and then assigned ColumnInfo <- rxGetVarInfo(sample_data). Then when importing in the rxDataStep (or rxImport if you want) I passed "colInfo = ColumnInfo". That worked very well.